# HTTP 500 error when I try to retrieve the audio file

Tags: java, http

I'm trying to get this Java program to receive audio files using a URL. When I do this, it just gives an error:

> javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input stream
>       at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
>       at Starter.main(Starter.java:21)

When you go to the URL in your browser, it downloads a file without a .mp3 extension with the hash that was used to store it in the database.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;

public class Starter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    AudioInputStream din = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=138738005");
        HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream bufferedIn = new BufferedInputStream(httpcon.getInputStream());
        //AudioInputStream in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Starter.class.getResourceAsStream("338876528.mp3"));
        AudioInputStream in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bufferedIn);
        AudioFormat baseFormat = in.getFormat();
        AudioFormat decodedFormat = new AudioFormat(
                AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
                baseFormat.getSampleRate(), 16, baseFormat.getChannels(),
                baseFormat.getChannels() * 2, baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
                false);
        din = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(decodedFormat, in);
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, decodedFormat);
        SourceDataLine line = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        if(line != null) {
            line.open(decodedFormat);
            byte[] data = new byte[4096];
            // Start
            line.start();

            int nBytesRead;
            while ((nBytesRead = din.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                line.write(data, 0, nBytesRead);
            }
            // Stop
            line.drain();
            line.stop();
            line.close();
            din.close();
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if(din != null) {
            try { din.close(); } catch(IOException e) { }
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want, but have a look at [this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653842/how-to-use-java-to-download-a-mp3-file-online) EDIT: Since I can't reply (below 50 rep), I'll just add this edit in here. First, like CaringDev said, it's not even an audio file at all. Second, I tried this code on something without the .mp3 extension, and it worked fine.

Comment: The file that the url returns doesn't have the .mp3 extension, so I'm not sure that it would work.

Answer (score 0):

The content of http://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=138738005 is

```
<roblox xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.roblox.com/roblox.xsd" version="4">
  <External>null</External>
  <External>nil</External>
  <Item class="ShirtGraphic" referent="RBX0">
    <Properties>
      <Content name="Graphic">
        <url>http://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=138738004</url>
      </Content>
      <string name="Name">Shirt Graphic</string>
      <bool name="archivable">true</bool>
    </Properties>
  </Item>
</roblox>
```

so I *would* expect an exception when trying to treat it as an audio file.
The file referenced in the url tag http://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=138738004 is a [PNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics):

[image: referenced file]

So, even extracting that would not help here.

Comment: @EncodedLua no, if you open the file there with e.g. Notepad++ you'll see that it contains the text I posted.

Comment: Oh, that's because on the site, sometimes you have to subtract from the soundid. I subtracted too much. The original is http://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=138738009. You then have to subtract 1 or 2 from it to get the audio file